# How can I delete characters from Strings inside a list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a **list** of many (18618) strings. I separated its words by implementing Tokenizing with NLTK library. But now each word - as in below- has an extra apostrophe and in some places **â**. How can I delete all of these?

I tried to delete them by implementing for loop but was unable to do it. What else can I do to solve this problem?

["'heart", "'darkness", "'nellie", "'cruising", "'yawl",    ....................................]

Comment: Can you provide a small list containin elements you want to keep / remove, as well as the desired result for that list?

Comment: Did you mean this?  New_List= [ " ' " , "â" ]

Comment: I want to delete in whole list " ' " and  "â".

Comment: Could this problem be related to Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

```py
lst = ["'heart", "'darkness", "'nellie", "'cruising", "'yawl"]

# for every txt in lst remove the ' and â
new_lst = [txt.replace("'", "").replace("â", "") for txt in lst]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your code works and the problem is solved easily.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this you may try decoding:

> Caution: when tokenizing a Unicode string, make sure you are not using an encoded version of the string (it may be necessary to decode it first, e.g. with `s.decode("utf8")`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My problem is solved by a for loop as above. Most probably as you said, my problem is related with decoding. I will focus on decoding issues after this.